# solve the exponential function

Tags: exponential-function

solve $(\sqrt6-\sqrt5)^x-\sqrt6-\sqrt5=0$

I know the result is $-1$ but I don't know how to prove it. I have tried to replace $\sqrt6-\sqrt5=t$ but then I have $t^x-t+2\sqrt5=0$ and I think it is wrong way in this case.

Comment: The important point is that $(\sqrt 6 - \sqrt 5)(\sqrt 6 + \sqrt 5)=6-5=1$

Answer (score 4):

$$(\sqrt{6}-\sqrt{5})^x=\sqrt{6}+\sqrt{5}$$
$$\frac{(\sqrt{6}-\sqrt{5})^x}{\sqrt{6}+\sqrt{5}}=1$$
$$\frac{(\sqrt{6}-\sqrt{5})^x}{\sqrt{6}+\sqrt{5}}\cdot\frac{\sqrt{6}-\sqrt{5}}{\sqrt{6}-\sqrt{5}}=1$$
$$\frac{(\sqrt{6}-\sqrt{5})^{x+1}}{1}=1$$

Can you finish from here?

Comment: sure, thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

$$(\sqrt6-\sqrt5)^x=\sqrt6+\sqrt5=\dfrac{(\sqrt6+\sqrt5)(\sqrt6-\sqrt5)}{\sqrt6-\sqrt5}=\dfrac{6-5}{\sqrt6-\sqrt5}.$$

Answer (score 1):

$$(\sqrt6-\sqrt5)^x-\sqrt6-\sqrt5=0$$
$$(\sqrt6-\sqrt5)^x=(\sqrt6+\sqrt5)$$
$$(\sqrt6-\sqrt5)^x=(\sqrt6+\sqrt5)\frac{\sqrt6-\sqrt5}{\sqrt6-\sqrt5}$$
$$(\sqrt6-\sqrt5)^x=\frac{1}{\sqrt6-\sqrt5}$$

$$(\sqrt6-\sqrt5)^x=(\sqrt6-\sqrt5)^{-1}$$ so $$x=-1$$